# Insert multiple location read from file in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add locations read from a file to google maps. I am referring to tutorials provided by google :
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/visualizing/earthquakes

Below html code is almost the same given in tutorials except i am reading from local file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script>
          var map;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 1,
          center: {lat: -33.865427, lng: 151.196123},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);

        // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'maps_data.txt';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }

      function test_callback(results) {
        map.data.addGeoJson(results);
      }

      // Call the initialize function after the page has finished loading
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

File from where I am reading coordinates is (maps_data.txt):

```
    test_callback({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[28.6139,77.2090]}}
    ]});
```

The problem is locations are not reflected properly. The coordinate mentioned in text file is for Delhi(INDIA) but it is showing somewhere else. 
Can you please point me out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of (at least) the last point are backwards, should be longitude, latitude: `[77.2090,28.6139]` not `[28.6139,77.2090]`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjqxe7x7/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 28.6,
      lng: 77.2
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  document.getElementById('center').innerHTML = "center: latitude:"+map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6)+" longitude:"+map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6)+" zoom:"+map.getZoom();
  test_callback({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-97.6846, 36.8293]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-66.1573, 18.4277]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-155.283, 19.3798333]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [77.2090, 28.6139]
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}

function test_callback(results) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(results);
}

// Call the initialize function after the page has finished loading
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```